# Iterating through an object with several json strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object, iteration

Sorry for the rookie question but I couldn't find an answer on similar questions.

I have an object made up of hundreds of json strings and I want to iterate through the object and return specific values from each string.

I have this code

```
 const leo =
   '{"contractName":"tokens","contractAction":"stake","contractPayload":{"to":"hivebuilder","symbol":"LEO","quantity":"0.161"}}';

 const obj = JSON.parse(leo);

 console.log(obj.contractPayload.to, obj.contractPayload.quantity);
```

Which returns:

```
hivebuilder 0.161
```

That's exactly what I want, but I want to do it to a nested json object like this:

```
const leo = [
  '{"contractName":"tokens","contractAction":"stake","contractPayload":{"to":"hivebuilder","symbol":"LEO","quantity":"0.161"}}',
  '{"contractName":"tokens","contractAction":"stake","contractPayload":{"to":"pele23","symbol":"LEO","quantity":"1.031"}}',
];
```

My expected result would be:

```
hivebuilder 0.161
pele23 1.031
```

I know I have to use a loop to iterate through each string, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it, any help please?

Comment: `leo.forEach((element) => {const obj = JSON.parse(element); then console log})`. basically same thing you did inside a for loop

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let names = leo.map(function (item) {
  const elem = JSON.parse(item);
  return elem.contractPayload.to + " " + elem.contractPayload.quantity;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(names));
```

result

```
["hivebuilder 0.161","pele23 1.031"]
```